# sqlite3 doesn't return error but does not insert data either

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert a few strings into my SQLite3 - Database with python. But when I run my Code it does not return an error, but it also does not insert the data.

I created the database like this:

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('databases/verification.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql = ('''
CREATE TABLE verification (
    verification_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    email_adress TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    username TEXT
)
''')

cursor.execute(sql)

connection.close()
```

and I try to insert my data like this

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('databases\\verification.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

verification_id = '1234567890'
email_adress = 'mymail@gmail.com'
password = 'superduperpassword'
username = 'admin'

sql = (f'''INSERT OR FAIL INTO verification (
                verification_id, 
                email_adress,
                password, 
                username) 
            VALUES (
                "{verification_id}",
                "{email_adress}",
                "{password}",
                "{username}"
            )
''')

cursor.execute(sql)

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you close your connection, you have to commit your changes:

```
(...)
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
(...)
connection.close()
```